# correct way to use mod_rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have followed lots of stackoverflow questions and Googling But i cant do my url rewrite correctly.
Here is an simple exapmle of my website

```
root-|
     |__mydomain-|
                 |
                -|
                 |__cat1-|__.htaccess
                 |       |__index.php
                 |       |__single.php
                 |
                 |__.htaccess
                 |__index.php  // home-page
```

my home page contains A menu link: **mysite.com/cat1**
->  which is showing "root/cat1/**index.php**" correctly.

**Question1:**
For any other links which contains cat1/post-id/title i need to rewrite url to **single.php?id=post-id**

```
mysite.com/cat1/123/title  
   ->  should show single php with content of post with id:123
```

What i wrote in root/cat1/.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteBase /cat1/


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ single.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

i get errors like

```
[Mon Nov 24 13:49:08.549284 2014] [:error] [pid 7144:tid 784] [client 127.0.0.1:21397]
script 'C:/wamp/www/single.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your rule a bit inside `/cat1/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cat1/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(.+?)/?$ single.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

**Make sure this is in `/cat1/.htaccess`**

PS: I added `title` parameter so that you can verify title is correct (if needed) inside `single.php` file.

Comment: THanks alot. but i still get The requested URL /cat1/single.php was not found on this server. it seems that it is looking for that file  in in **root/cat1/single.php** not in **root/mydomain/cat1/single.php** because when i create a simple file in this path: **root/cat1/single.php** it shows up!!

Comment: i uploaded the `.htaccess` to my host and it works there! but in my local i still have problem. it seems to be some problem with wamp server in my local

Comment: Ok so problem seems to be this extra `/mydomain/` folder on your localhost which is not there on live server. On localhost use `RewriteBase` line as `RewriteBase /mydomain/cat1/`

Comment: Great!! :) that works now but just one more issue!     
**`cat1/1/2/`** in Firefox and chrome give **`Array( [id] => 1 [title] => 2/ )`**  while **`cat1/1/2`** in Firefox give **`Array( [id] => 1 [title] => 2 )`** but in chrome Shows a `Not FOUND page`!

Comment: ok I made a small change to strip off trailing slash. Try it in both browsers.